# Assigning first column for text file to list

Tags: python

My input file looks like this:

```
5MAX 5StarMax.us
ABCNL ABCNewsLive.us
AMC AMC.us
```

I can read the whole file into a list with this:

`MyLines=open("MyFile.txt",'r').read().splitlines()`

While produces this list:

`['5MAX 5StarMax.us', 'ABCNL ABCNewsLive.us', 'AMC AMC.us']`

But all I really want is the is first column in the list, like this:

`['5MAX', 'ABCNL', 'AMC']`

The following code gets the job done, but I've got think there's a better way.

```
MyLines=[]
for x in open("MyFile.txt",'r'):
  MyLines.append(x.split(' ')[0])
```

(Please forgive any typos or missing parens or quotes or brackets, I'm typing this all freehand)

So does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can type:

```
lines = open("MyFile.txt",'r').read().splitlines()

my_words = [ s.split(' ')[0] for s in lines ]
```

Or even :

```
my_words = [s.split(' ')[0] for s in open("MyFile.txt","r")]
```

Comment: If you're just getting the first element, then tell `str.split` to only split once at most: `s.split(' ', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```py
MyLines = []

with open("MyFile.txt", "r") as file:
    MyLines = [line.split()[0] for line in file1.readlines()]
```

You can take a look at the [Read a file line by line in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/) blog for other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could still do it with one line using a comprehension

```
[ c for c,*_ in map(str.split,open("MyFile.txt",'r').readlines()) ]
```